# Grails external configuration

Tags: grails, configuration

I put my `Log4jConfig.groovy` in `grails-app/conf/configs/`

And I got an exception like this:

```
...nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: configs.Log4jConfig
```

In my Config.groovy:

```
def configsLocation = [Log4jConfig]
environments {
    development {
        grails.config.locations = configsLocation
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I put my `Log4jConfig.groovy` in `grails-app/conf/configs/`" - does that file have `package configs` at the top of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to specify the package `configs` while specifying the config location. Something like below will yield you appropriate result:

```
//Config.groovy
def configsLocation = [configs.Log4jConfig]
environments {
    development {
        grails.config.locations = configsLocation
    }
}

//grails-app/conf/configs/Log4jConfig.groovy
package configs //specify the package in config as well
my.foo = 1234
my.bar = "ABCD"

//Grails Console or Unit Test or render from controller
assert 1234 == grailsApplication.config.my.foo
assert "ABCD" == grailsApplication.config.my.bar
```