# Grails - split Config.groovy into multiple files

Tags: grails

For Grails 2.2.x -

I'd like to split Config.groovy into multiple files in the same grails-app/conf folder.

Is that possible?

I am aware of grails.config.locations, but that doesn't seem to work all that well - I have to put the files in src/java for them to be picked up in the classpath, and they don't refresh in development unless I restart

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put `Class` objects into `grails.config.locations`:

```
grails.config.locations = [ConfigOne, ConfigTwo]
```

This would load configuration from `ConfigOne.groovy` and `ConfigTwo.groovy` (which could be in `grails-app/conf` or in `src/groovy`), and you can mix and match this style with the normal runtime-parsed `.groovy` and `.properties` external configs.

I don't know whether these files will get reloaded in dev mode though.

Comment: +1. Just to make sure you are not facing [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17428916/2051952), use `package` appropriately.

Comment: what would the ConfigOne.groovy classes look like?  Would these just look like Config.groovy or do they need to be wrapped in `class ConfigOne {...}`?

Comment: @wrschneider99 they'd be scripts the same as `Config.groovy` or a normal external `.groovy` config file.

Comment: Ok, got it to work - I was missing that I needed the `package` at the top even though it doesn't look like a normal Groovy class.  But `ConfigOne, ConfigTwo` in the above example will not hot-load changes.